# how to pass function defined inside directive to another directive?

Tags: angularjs

I need to pass function defined in directive to another one , my code is something like below

```js
angular
  .module('myApp')

  .controller('myAppCtrl', function($scope) {})

  .directive('first', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        originFn: '&',
      },
      template: '<button ng-click="originFn()" >Click</button>',
      controller: function() {
        var self = this;

        self.originFn = function() {
          console.log('called from First');
        };
      },
    };
  })

  .directive('second', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        passedFn: '&',
      },
      template: '<button ng-click="passedFn()" >Click</button>',
    };
  });
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
  <first origin-fn="originFn" />
  <second passed-fn="originFn" />
</div>;
```

when click on second button origin function not called ,

> How can pass function to be called inside second directive ?

Answer (score 0):

Both of directives are siblings, there is nothing in common, one directive can't call other directive controller without being it child.

So, if you can nest second directive into the first, you can use `require` functionality to get the parent directive controller.

```js
.directive('second', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^^first',
        scope: {},
        template: '<button ng-click="innerFunc()" >Click</button>',
        link: function ($scope, $elem, $attr, firstCtrl) {
          // -------------------------------------^
          $scope.innerFunc = firstCtrl.originFn;
        }
    };
})
```

```html
<div ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
  <first>
    <second></second>
  </first>
</div>
```

For more complete [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate).

Comment: felixmosh , it correct to use firstCtrl controller and it belong to first directive and what if have another directives between this div , how can make it as controller for hole div

Comment: as you defined it, it is an **app** controller, not a directive one.

Comment: I've updated my answer, both of the directives are calling to the same function on `firstCtrl`

Comment: what if both directives are not siblings , and can`t be child , any solution for this problem ?

Comment: if you need that both of them will be able to invoke the same function, that means that this function should be at the common parent. (not inside one of the directives).